# jQuery Find Width of Block Element

Tags: jquery, width, inline, block

Is there an easy way to determine the width of a `block` element if it were to be `inline`? I can't make the elements `inline` so I need some way to determine how wide it should be and then modify the width.

Comment: could you set the element to inline, take the width, then reset it to block with the width?

Comment: If you want to submit that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have done it with the help of polyhedron. Here is the code if someone finds it on Google.

```
$("h1").each(function() {
    $(this).css("display","inline").css({width: $(this).width(), display: "block"});
});
```